# WARNING: API 'variant.getPackageLibrary()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getPackageLibraryProvider()'

Tags: kotlin, android-gradle-plugin

I just upadated kotlin to 1.3.30 and I now get this error when syncing gradle:

> WARNING: API 'variant.getPackageLibrary()' is obsolete and has been
>   replaced with 'variant.getPackageLibraryProvider()'. It will be
>   removed at the end of 2019. For more information, see
>   https://d.android.com/r/tools/task-configuration-avoidance. To
>   determine what is calling variant.getPackageLibrary(), use
>   -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true on the command line to display a stack trace. Affected Modules: hydatabase

Here is my `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.squareup.sqldelight'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-multiplatform'
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

sqldelight {
    Database {
        packageName = "com.company.hydatabase"
    }
}

kotlin {
    targets {
        fromPreset(presets.jvm, 'jvm')
        fromPreset(presets.android, 'android')
    }

    sourceSets {
        commonMain.dependencies {
            api 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common'
        }
        jvmMain.dependencies {
            api 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8'
            // ICU4J: Use DecimalFormat
            // Get rid of this when minSDKLevel = API 24 - Nougat (7.0)
            // https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/internationalization.html
            api 'com.ibm.icu:icu4j:60.2'
        }
        androidMain.dependencies {
            implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib'
            api "com.squareup.sqldelight:android-driver:1.1.1"
        }
        androidMain.dependsOn jvmMain
    }
}

task copyDatabase(type: Copy) {
    from "${rootProject.file('hyappcommon/Databases/').path}"
    into "${rootProject.file('hydatabase/src/main/assets/databases/').path}"
    include '**/*.sqlite'
}

preBuild.dependsOn(copyDatabase)

// workaround for https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-27170
configurations {
    compileClasspath
}
```

Answer (score 56, accepted):

If you debug, it shows
`REASON: The Kotlin plugin is currently calling this API. We are working to solve this.`

To see this error please run
`./gradlew -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true --stacktrace`

Comment: where do you see this?

Comment: `./gradlew -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true --stacktrace`

Comment: I upgraded 'kotlin-gradle-plugin'  version from 1.3.31 to 1.3.41 and  warning removed Thanks

Comment: Where should I run `./gradlew ...` ?

Comment: I am using 1.3.61 version then also facing this problem.. please help me with the solution.. Thank you n happy coding..

Answer (score 11):

As tommyboy said, the Kotlin plugin is calling this deprecated API.
If you don't want to get this warning while Kotlin is working on this, you can just use the previous version of Kotlin plugin like:

```
dependencies {
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.21"
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It's probably a bug and fixed soon

You can revert back to the previous version or add this line to `gradle.properties`

```
android.debug.obsoleteApi=true
```

Answer (score 4):

In my project gradle file I had

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.31'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

Simple changing 
`ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.31'` to `ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.41'` solved the problem

when using version 1.3.31 i had tried `gradlew -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true`

It mentioned

> WARNING: API 'variant.getPackageLibrary()' is obsolete and has been
>   replaced with 'variant.getPackageLibraryProvider()'. It will be
>   removed at the end of 2019.
>   For more information, see https://d.android.com/r/tools/task-configuration-avoidance.
>
> **REASON: The Kotlin plugin is currently calling this API. We are working to solve this.**
>
> WARNING: Debugging obsolete API calls can take time during
>   configuration. It's recommended to not keep it on at all times.

Looks like it is solved in 1.3.41

Answer (score 3):

It's an issue with the Kotlin plugin, as [mentioned here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-30784). It'll get fixed in a later version.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: @double-beep
Short answer not synonyme for bad answer.

Comment: "It's an issue with Kotlin plugin" doesn't really answer the question. You can expand the answer - please do it.

Answer (score 1):

After I updated Kotlin to `1.3.30`, the following dependencies cause the error:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.8.4'
    classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:2.1'
    // ... other dependencies
}
```

I have reported the issue here:

https://github.com/bintray/gradle-bintray-plugin/issues/284

https://github.com/dcendents/android-maven-gradle-plugin/issues/81

By the way, you can ignore that error message.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is [tracked here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-30784) and it is **fixed.**

Just use the Kotlin Gradle plugin v **1.3.40 or higher.**

> WARNING: API 'variant.getPackageLibrary()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getPackageLibraryProvider()'.
>   It will be removed at the end of 2019.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just updated to "v1.3.40-release-Studio3.4-1" plugin.

as you can see in https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-30784

Answer (score 0):

I met this problem when I use kotlin plugin with library plugin. I found that if you use kotlin plugin with application plugin, it works well. But if you use kotlin plugin with library plugin, it will cause this problem. So that means:

```
// work well:
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

// error:
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

As the error diplayed that, you can use `./gradlew -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true --stacktrace` to find out with module caused this problem.

Then I found that one of my module used the wrong plugin combination above. And that seems to be a bug of kotlin plugin. So finally, I upgraded the kotlin plugin, and then it worked well. Below is the kotlin plugin that I finally used:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.40'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can run this command in the root project

```
gradlew -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true
```

and the warning will be disappeared.